# RuntimeError: You should not call `__bool__` / `__nonzero__` on `Formula`,

Tags: jupyter-notebook, drake

I was trying to write a least time control code, using drake toolbox. But in the middle, I cannot understand the error info: (please ignore things happened in this parentheis, i just don't know how much detail is needed to submit the post, god!)

'''python
    from pydrake.all import MathematicalProgram, Solve
    import numpy as np

```
def g(x):
    if abs(x)<1e-7:
        return 0.
    else:
        return 1.

mp = MathematicalProgram()

state_initial = np.asarray([1., 0])
position_goal = np.asarray([0,  0])

N=100
dt=0.01
u_over_time=mp.NewContinuousVariables(1,"u_0")
states_over_time = np.asarray([state_initial])
for k in range(1,N):
    u = mp.NewContinuousVariables(1, "u_%d" % k)
    state =mp.NewContinuousVariables(2,"state_%d" % k)
    u_over_time = np.vstack((u_over_time, u))
    states_over_time = np.vstack((states_over_time,state))

print "Number of decision vars", mp.num_vars()
for i in range(N-1):
    state_next0 = states_over_time[i,0]+  dt*states_over_time[i,1]
    state_next1 = states_over_time[i,1]+  dt*u_over_time[i]
    mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,0]>=state_next0)
    mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,1]>=state_next1)
    mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,0]<=state_next0)
    mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,1]<=state_next1)
    mp.AddLinearConstraint(u_over_time[i]<=1.)
    mp.AddLinearConstraint(u_over_time[i]>=-1.)
```

```
And the error info is :
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-be1aa565be42> in <module>()
     29     state_next1 = states_over_time[i,1]+  dt*u_over_time[i]
     30     mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,0]>=state_next0)
---> 31     mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,1]>=state_next1)
     32     mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,0]<=state_next0)
     33     mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,1]<=state_next1)

RuntimeError: You should not call `__bool__` / `__nonzero__` on `Formula`. If you are trying to make a map with `Variable`, `Expression`, or `Polynomial` as keys (and then access the map in Python), please use pydrake.common.containers.EqualToDict`.

May I know what's happening here? Thanks

----------------update line-----------------
I modified the code as you told me. Now the code now becomes:

'''python
    from pydrake.all import MathematicalProgram, Solve
    import numpy as np

    def g(x):
        if abs(x)<1e-7:
            return 0.
        else:
            return 1.

    mp = MathematicalProgram()

    state_initial = np.asarray([1., 0])
    position_goal = np.asarray([0,  0])

    N=100
    dt=0.01
    u_over_time=mp.NewContinuousVariables(1,"u_0")
    states_over_time = np.asarray([state_initial])
    for k in range(1,N):
        u = mp.NewContinuousVariables(1, "u_%d" % k)
        state =mp.NewContinuousVariables(2,"state_%d" % k)
        u_over_time = np.vstack((u_over_time, u))
        states_over_time = np.vstack((states_over_time,state))

    print "Number of decision vars", mp.num_vars()
    for i in range(N-1):
        state_next0 = states_over_time[i,0]+  dt*states_over_time[i,1]
        state_next1 = states_over_time[i,1]+  dt*u_over_time[i,0]
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,0]>=state_next0[0])
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,1]>=state_next1[0])
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,0]<=state_next0[0])
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,1]<=state_next1[0])
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(u_over_time[i,0]<=1.)
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(u_over_time[i,0]>=-1.)
'''

And the error info is:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-82e68c2ebfaa> in <module>()
     27     state_next0 = states_over_time[i,0]+  dt*states_over_time[i,1]
     28     state_next1 = states_over_time[i,1]+  dt*u_over_time[i,0]
---> 29     mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,0]>=state_next0[0])
     30     mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,1]>=state_next1[0])
     31     mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,0]<=state_next0[0])

TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

What's the problem this time? Thanks.

(Btw, one of my complain is that, the error info always not that effective to give the hint of where the problem is...)

-----------------update 2nd time line--------------------
Now a similar problem happened to the g(x), the code:
'''
    from pydrake.all import MathematicalProgram, Solve
    import numpy as np

    def g(x):
        print 'x=',x
        print 'x[0]=',x[0]
        if x[0]*x[0]+x[1]*x[1]<1e-7: # x.dot(x)
            return 0.
        else:
            return 1.

    mp = MathematicalProgram()

    state_initial = np.asarray([1., 0])
    #position_goal = np.asarray([0,  0]) # already in g(x)

    N=100
    dt=0.01
    u_over_time=mp.NewContinuousVariables(1,"u_0")
    states_over_time = np.asarray([state_initial])
    for k in range(1,N):
        u = mp.NewContinuousVariables(1, "u_%d" % k)
        state =mp.NewContinuousVariables(2,"state_%d" % k)
        u_over_time = np.vstack((u_over_time, u))
        states_over_time = np.vstack((states_over_time,state))

    print "Number of decision vars", mp.num_vars()
    for i in range(N-1):
        state_next0 = states_over_time[i,0]+  dt*states_over_time[i,1]
        state_next1 = states_over_time[i,1]+  dt*u_over_time[i,0]
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,0]>=state_next0)
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,1]>=state_next1)
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,0]<=state_next0)
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,1]<=state_next1)
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(u_over_time[i,0]<=1.)
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(u_over_time[i,0]>=-1.)
    reward=np.zeros((N,1))
    for i in range(N):
        reward[i]=g(states_over_time[i,:])

    mp.AddQuadraticCost(reward.dot(reward))
    result=Solve(mp)
'''
This time neither x or x[0] could solve the problem. the output info is :

Number of decision vars 298
x= [1.0 0.0]
x[0]= 1.0
x= [Variable('state_1(0)', Continuous) Variable('state_1(1)', Continuous)]
x[0]= state_1(0)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-08d1cd75397e> in <module>()
     37 reward=np.zeros((N,1))
     38 for i in range(N):
---> 39     reward[i]=g(states_over_time[i,:])
     40 
     41 mp.AddQuadraticCost(reward.dot(reward))

<ipython-input-8-08d1cd75397e> in g(x)
      5     print 'x=',x
      6     print 'x[0]=',x[0]
----> 7     if x[0]*x[0]+x[1]*x[1]<1e-7: # x.dot(x)
      8         return 0.
      9     else:

RuntimeError: You should not call `__bool__` / `__nonzero__` on `Formula`. If you are trying to make a map with `Variable`, `Expression`, or `Polynomial` as keys (and then access the map in Python), please use pydrake.common.containers.EqualToDict`.

What can I do this time? Thanks
Btw, you see in the code i print x or x[0] only once, but i got two different answer? funny, isn't it? why is this?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`state_next1` is not a symbolic expression, it is a numpy array of symbolic expression, so you need to do `state_next1[0]`. Similarly you will need to change `u_over_time[i] <= 1` to `u_over_time[i, 0] <= 1`.

The other way to solve the problem is to compute `state_next1` using `u_overt_time[i, 0]` instead of `u_over_time[i]`. After modification, the for loop in your code should be

```
for i in range(N-1):
    state_next0 = states_over_time[i,0]+  dt*states_over_time[i,1]
    state_next1 = states_over_time[i,1]+  dt*u_over_time[i, 0]
    mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,0]>=state_next0)
    mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,1]>=state_next1)
    mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,0]<=state_next0)
    mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,1]<=state_next1)
    mp.AddLinearConstraint(u_over_time[i, 0]<=1.)
    mp.AddLinearConstraint(u_over_time[i, 0]>=-1.)
```

I changed `u_over_time[i]` to `u_over_time[i, 0]` where you define `state_next1`.

Comment: Thanks. So even state_next is a scala arraynumpy, we still cannot access it by only its variable name?

Comment: Now the error info becomes: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-82e68c2ebfaa> in <module>()
     27     state_next0 = states_over_time[i,0]+  dt*states_over_time[i,1]
     28     state_next1 = states_over_time[i,1]+  dt*u_over_time[i,0]
---> 29     mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,0]>=state_next0[0])
     30     mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,1]>=state_next1[0])
     31     mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,0]<=state_next0[0])

TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: > Thanks. So even state_next is a scala arraynumpy, we still cannot access it by only its variable name?

If you call u_over_time[i], the type is a numpy array. Then when you call `mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,1]>=state_next1)`, the left-hand side `states_over_time[i+1, 1]` is a symbolic variable, and the right-handside is a numpy array. We currently don't support this function call.

Comment: Could you update and paste your current code? I cannot reproduce your newest error.

Comment: finally updated, it cost me half an hour to handle the "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more detail" to submit. looks like that ONLY the number of words in the first paragraph counts!

Comment: The error occurs because you have state_next0[0]. state_next0 is a float, you cannot access its first element. These lines should be changed to

    for i in range(N-1):
        state_next0 = states_over_time[i,0]+  dt*states_over_time[i,1]
        state_next1 = states_over_time[i,1]+  dt*u_over_time[i,0]
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,0]>=state_next0)
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,1]>=state_next1)
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,0]<=state_next0)

Comment: I met a new similar problem, will you have a look at it? about the use of g(x) in the code. I update the post by the 2nd update line. No matter how i wrote it, including x[0]*x[0]+x[1]*x[1], or x.dot(x) or abs(x) or np.linalg.norm(x), these all failed... @Hongkai Dai

Answer (score 0):

The error thrown in the line

```
if x[0]*x[0]+x[1]*x[1]<1e-7: # x.dot(x)
    return 0.
```

is because you called with `AddQuadraticCost`, but your cost is not quadratic. Drake tries to parse the symbolic expression as a quadratic expression, and failed. Specifically Drake fails when you check if the expression x[0] * x[0] + x[1] * x[1] < 1e-7. No quadratic cost can have this type of "if" statement.

What is the mathematical formulation of your cost? Do you really want to impose the cost as defined in your `g(x)` function, that if x'*x < 1e-7, then g(x) = 0, otherwise g(x) = 1? This is a pretty bad cost (it is almost constant everywhere, but have discrete jumps from 1 to 0 near the origin).

Since you want to solve a least time optimal control problem, I would suggest to change your formulation, and make `dt` a decision variable in your problem. Namely you will have the dynamic constraint

```
x[n+1] = x[n] + f(x[n], u[n]) * dt[n]
```

The final state constraint

```
x[N] = x_desired
```

The initial state constraint

```
x[0] = x_initial
```

And your cost function is to minimize the time

```
min sum_i dt[i]
```

Then you will have smooth cost and constraint.

Comment: No, the reason of the error is not quadratic cost, since the code has not run into that line yet. I deleted a random letter for the line AdQudraticCost , the error info did not even change.  I think the reason may still the data type, but I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Btw, to deal with the least time control, the way I used is the method prof tedrake recommended in class, I did not like it at first, but soon i found myself cannot come up a better idea... another reason that i accepted this way is that the ACADO toolbox also handle the least time control as QP optimization, although i don't know the how they did it.  I did not like your way, the introducing of dt, makes the problem nonlinear, not to mention we don't know the value of N yet. And dt is something relates to the accuracy of the solution of ODE, not a good idea to make it decision variable.

Comment: You don't get a convex or QP problem in your formulation. A QP formulation does not allow an `if` statement in its cost/constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code that doesn't throw syntax error

```
    from pydrake.all import MathematicalProgram, Solve
    import numpy as np

    def g(x):
        x_squared_norm = np.power(x.reshape((2, -1)), 2)
        return np.sum(x_squared_norm > 1e-7)

    mp = MathematicalProgram()

    state_initial = np.asarray([1., 0])
    #position_goal = np.asarray([0,  0]) # already in g(x)

    N=100
    dt=0.01
    u_over_time=mp.NewContinuousVariables(1,"u_0")
    states_over_time = np.asarray([state_initial])
    for k in range(1,N):
        u = mp.NewContinuousVariables(1, "u_%d" % k)
        state =mp.NewContinuousVariables(2,"state_%d" % k)
        u_over_time = np.vstack((u_over_time, u))
        states_over_time = np.vstack((states_over_time,state))

    print "Number of decision vars", mp.num_vars()
    for i in range(N-1):
        state_next0 = states_over_time[i,0]+  dt*states_over_time[i,1]
        state_next1 = states_over_time[i,1]+  dt*u_over_time[i,0]
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,0]>=state_next0)
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,1]>=state_next1)
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,0]<=state_next0)
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,1]<=state_next1)
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(u_over_time[i,0]<=1.)
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(u_over_time[i,0]>=-1.)
    mp.AddCost(g, vars=states_over_time[1:,:].reshape((1, -1)).squeeze())
    result=Solve(mp)
```

Notice that I changed the definition of `g`, and called `mp.AddCost` instead of `mp.AddQuadraticCost`. `mp.AddQuadraticCost` expects a quadratic symbolic expression. The expression in your code is not quadratic (it has an `if` statement in the cost, and quadratic cost doesn't allow `if` statement.).

This code should run without error, but I don't know if it can find the solution. Again this cost is not differentiable, so any gradient based nonlinear solver will have trouble.

If you really don't want to solve the problem as a nonlinear optimization problem, you can consider to re-formulate the problem as a mixed-integer program. Namely your cost is the summation of a bunch of binary variables `b[i]`, that `b[i] = 1 if |x[i, 0]| > epsilon or |x[i, 1]| > epsilon; otherwise b[i] = 0`, and your can formulate this as a mixed-integer linear constraints.

Comment: When I run this piece of code. The service died. Didn't this happen to you?

Comment: No, it runs fine on my machine. What version of Drake do you use? I ran it on the newest version of Drake with Python 3.6 (after I remove that print line). Could you try running the code with the newest Drake?

Comment: i'm using the one with python2.7, under jupyter notebook

Comment: I think i finally realize that the "bool" mentioned in the error info means the "if" I'm using. wheneve there is a decision variable, i cannot use "if"...

Comment: The code you are using is LQR without input regulation, it's not least time optimal control. The mixed integer programming is the right way. But there is skill needed to transform the g(x) function to MI linear constraint. I'm stil working on that

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer by bisection method, which also recommended by tedrake on class. but I don't like this method. Too many iterations. I just put it here, when i have a mixed integer code, i will back.

god, i just cannot pass the code check...i really hate the code check machanism of stackoverflow...

'''
    from pydrake.all import MathematicalProgram, Solve
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    '''
    def g(x):
        print 'x=',x
        print 'x[0]=',x[0]
        if x[0]*x[0]+x[1]*x[1]<1e-7: # x.dot(x)
            return 0.
        else:
            return 1.
    '''
    #mp = MathematicalProgram()

```
state_initial = np.asarray([1., 0])
#position_goal = np.asarray([0,  0]) # already in g(x)

#N=201
dt=0.01
upper=1000; lower=1;
N=upper
while upper-lower>1:
    print '---------------------'
    print 'N=',N
    mp = MathematicalProgram()
    u_over_time=mp.NewContinuousVariables(1,"u_0")
    states_over_time = mp.NewContinuousVariables(2,"state intial")
    mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[0]==np.asarray([state_initial[0]]))
    mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[1]==np.asarray([state_initial[1]]))
    #states_over_time = np.asarray([state_initial])
    for k in range(1,N):
        u = mp.NewContinuousVariables(1, "u_%d" % k)
        state =mp.NewContinuousVariables(2,"state_%d" % k)
        u_over_time = np.vstack((u_over_time, u))
        states_over_time = np.vstack((states_over_time,state))

    print "Number of decision vars", mp.num_vars()
    for i in range(N-1):
        state_next0 = states_over_time[i,0]+  dt*states_over_time[i,1]
        state_next1 = states_over_time[i,1]+  dt*u_over_time[i,0]
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,0]>=state_next0)
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,1]>=state_next1)
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,0]<=state_next0)
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[i+1,1]<=state_next1)
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(u_over_time[i,0]<=1.)
        mp.AddLinearConstraint(u_over_time[i,0]>=-1.)
    '''
    reward=np.zeros((N,1))
    for i in range(N):
        reward[i]=g(states_over_time[i,:])
    '''
    mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[-1,0]<=1e-7)
    mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[-1,1]<=1e-7)
    mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[-1,0]>=1e-7)
    mp.AddLinearConstraint(states_over_time[-1,1]>=1e-7)
    #mp.AddQuadraticCost(reward.dot(reward))

    result=Solve(mp)
    print result.is_success()
    if result.is_success():
        upper=N
    else:
        lower=N
    N=lower+int((upper-lower)/2.0)
N=upper
#print result.is_success()
print 'least time=',dt*N
u_over_time=result.GetSolution(u_over_time)
states_over_time=result.GetSolution(states_over_time)
#print 'u=',u_over_time
#print 'last state=',states_over_time[-1,:]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1);plt.plot(np.arange(dt, dt*N, dt),u_over_time);
plt.legend(["u against t"])
plt.subplot(2, 1, 2);plt.plot(states_over_time[:,0],states_over_time[:,1]);
plt.legend(["phase portrait"])
```

'''