# RuntimeError: You should not call `__bool__` / `__nonzero__` on `Formula`

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, drake

I am working on Exercise 3.9 (virtual wall) from Russ Tedrake's Robotic Manipulation course, and I'm receiving the runtime error above when attempting to add the end-effector position constraint. I've been stuck on this almost all day, so I caved and decided to post. Another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59335527/runtimeerror-you-should-not-call-bool-nonzero-on-formula) had a similar error, but it wasn't enough for me to see what's going wrong. I'll try to give as little information as necessary to avoid showing my solution to the problem.

Here is the code with some lines missing.

```
prog = MathematicalProgram()
      v = prog.NewContinuousVariables(7, 'joint_velocities')
      v_max = 3.0 # do not modify
      h = 4e-3 # do not modify
      lower_bound = np.array([-0.3, -1.0, -1.0]) # do not modify
      upper_bound = np.array([0.3, 1.0, 1.0]) # do not modify
```

In the following, 'p' is an array of symbolic expressions that depend on elements of 'v'.

```
  for i in range(p.shape[0]):
    prog.AddConstraint(le(lower_bound[i], p[i]))
    prog.AddConstraint(ge(upper_bound[i], p[i]))

  solver = SnoptSolver()
  result = solver.Solve(prog)
    
  if not (result.is_success()):
    raise ValueError("Could not find the optimal solution.")

  v_solution = result.GetSolution(v)
  return v_solution
```

And here is the error message. The first line in the for loop is where the error occurs.

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-b73c5373ad6c> in <module>()
      1 V_d = np.array([0.0, 0., 0., 0.1, 0.05, 0])
----> 2 simulator = BuildAndSimulate(DiffIKQP_Wall, V_d)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args)
   2144 
   2145             inputs = [arg.flat[0] for arg in args]
-> 2146             outputs = func(*inputs)
   2147 
   2148             # Performance note: profiling indicates that -- for simple

RuntimeError: You should not call `__bool__` / `__nonzero__` on `Formula`. If you are trying to make a map with `Variable`, `Expression`, or `Polynomial` as keys (and then access the map in Python), please use pydrake.common.containers.EqualToDict`.
```

Please let me know if have any suggestions or you need more information.

Thanks!

Edit:

I thought this information might be helpful. Running

```
print(type(lower_bound[i]))
print(type(p[i]))
```

returns

```
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'pydrake.symbolic.Expression'>
```

Comment: can you confirm that you've done `from pydrake.all import le, ge` at the top?

Comment: Yes, I imported them. @RussTedrake

Comment: perhaps you can post a link to some runnable code so I can take a look?

Comment: Sure, thanks for taking a look, https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RxFtWnqgaZgMtGmAnRTiDRERossY2lL0?usp=sharing. @RussTedrake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... i'm embarassed.  But I think you've found a bug in our python bindings.

```
from pydrake.all import Variable, le, ge
x = Variable("x")

print(2 <= x**2)
print(x**2 <= 2)
print(le(x**2, 2))
#print(le(2, x**2))  <== this crashes

print(ge(x**2, 2))
#print(ge(2, x**2))  <== this too.
```

I've opened: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/15549

But for now, please pick any of the other ways to write the same constraint?

Comment: Interesting! No worries, my code is working now. I really can't express how thankful I am for your open courseware and Drake. As an undergrad doing robotics research, your work is very helpful! Thank you for being so generous with your time. @RussTedrake

Answer (score 0):

BTW, I would suggest not to use the symbolic version of constraint here. It seems to me that your symbolic expression `p` is complicated (namely it is not a linear expression of the decision variables). Adding this symbolic formulation of constraint slows down the solver compuation, as the solver needs to evaluate the symbolic expression in every iteration. If `p` is a position of the robot link, then I suggest to use `PositionConstraint` described in https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.multibody.inverse_kinematics.html?highlight=positionconstraint#pydrake.multibody.inverse_kinematics.PositionConstraint

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I will keep that in mind moving forward. Since this is an 'exercise,' I'd like to figure out what's causing the error, so I can implement my constraint, albeit poorly formulated. Unless you think my symbolic formulation may be causing the error? @HongkaiDai